# How to run Jenkins on foreground?

Tags: windows, jenkins, foreground

is there any way to force Jenkins job to run on foreground?

this is the script I use to start the Job.

```
cd %LibPath%
java -cp "%LibPath%/*;" STARTJenkins %TestPlanName% %User% %Password% NONE %WORKSPACE%
```

Issue seems to persist only if user running Jenkins is locked